# IOS Container View and Push Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue, container-view

I have a container view which is linked to a child view controller with embed segue and it is linked to  another view controller(My View Controller) with push segue on a button.

My problem is; I can't display a subview that is added in container view in My View Controller with storyboard configuration like [figure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2g2hw2csogwcq5y/Screen%20Shot%20Container.png).

If I added one more same container view(Banner View Controller) before My View Controller, exists infinite loop.

How should i do to solve this issue?

I use [Apple's TabbedBanner iAd With StoryBoard example](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/iAdSuite_Storyboard/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Try showing some of your work. It can go a long way towards having people help you.

Comment: I added sample used in my question according to reply of @NicolasMoise.